# Change Inner text color in Javascript code

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and I just copy a code for Download Button Counter. Now I want to change the text color of the counter. Could anybody help me?

**Code**

```js
var downloadButton = document.getElementById("download");
var counter = 30;
var newElement = document.createElement("p");
newElement.innerHTML = "Job Advertisement will be visible after 30 Seconds ";
var id;
downloadButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, downloadButton);
id = setInterval(function() {
  counter--;
  if (counter < 0) {
    newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton, newElement);
    clearInterval(id);
  } else {

    newElement.innerHTML = "You can download the file in " + counter.toString() + " seconds.";

  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="download">Download</button>
</div>
```

Comment: How about using [css](https://www.w3schools.com/css/)? Does it have to be javascript? If so, set the style attribute: `element.style = "color: whatever"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS `color` property.

```
newElement.innerHTML = "<span style='color:green;'>You can download the file in " + counter.toString() + " seconds.</span>";
```

You can use classes as well.

```
newElement.innerHTML = "<span class='text-primary'>You can download the file in " + counter.toString() + " seconds.</span>";
```

Comment: Can I also use bootstrap here?

Comment: @PakWorkForce Yes.

Comment: @PakWorkForce No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**newElement.style.color = "*red*"**

Or whatever color you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code for you requirement.

```js
var downloadButton = document.getElementById("download");
var counter = 30;
var newElement = document.createElement("p");
newElement.innerHTML = "Job Advertisement will be visible after <span style='color: red;'>30</span> Seconds";
var id;
downloadButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, downloadButton);
id = setInterval(function() {
  counter--;
  if (counter < 0) {
    newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton, newElement);
    clearInterval(id);
  } else {

    newElement.innerHTML = "You can download the file in <span style='color: red;'>" + counter.toString() + "</span> seconds.";

  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="download">Download</button>
</div>
```